# How to implement @Binds to an interface if the class implementing it is a Fragment

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have a recyclerview and an adapter that displays a list, and I want to implement a click listener to each item where the callback of it will be in a fragment. I have made an interface called `OnItemSelectListener` and I implemented it in the fragment. I've used constructor injection to inject the interface to the adapter. And then I have made a module where I've used @Binds to provide the interface. But the implementation of my interface is a fragment, and as expected I am getting this error:

[image]

This is how I made the @Binds annotated function for the `OnItemSelectListener`. I know this is not the right way:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
abstract class AlarmsModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindOnItemSelectListener(
        alarmsFragment: AlarmsFragment
    ): AlarmsRvAdapter.OnItemSelectListener
}
```

This is my fragment that implements the OnItemSelectListener:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AlarmsFragment constructor(
    private val alarmsRvAdapter: AlarmsRvAdapter
) : Fragment(), AlarmsRvAdapter.OnItemSelectListener {
    private val alarmsViewModel: AlarmsViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private var alarmsList = mutableListOf<Alarm>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarms, container, false)
        setUpAlarmsRecyclerView(view)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        alarmsViewModel.alarmsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            alarmsList.clear()
            alarmsList.addAll(it)
            alarmsRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })

        return view
    }

    private fun setUpAlarmsRecyclerView(view: View) {
        // Set up recyclerview
        val rvAlarms = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvAlarms)
        rvAlarms.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvAlarms.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))

        // Set up adapter
        context?.let {
            alarmsRvAdapter.alarmsList = alarmsList
            rvAlarms.adapter = alarmsRvAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        alarmsViewModel.alarmFormLiveData.value = alarmsList[position]
    }

    ....
}
```

I also made a factory for the fragment because I am using the Navigation Component:

```
class AlarmsFragmentFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val alarmsRvAdapter: AlarmsRvAdapter
): FragmentFactory() {
    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment {
        return when (className) {
            AlarmsFragment::class.java.name -> {
                AlarmsFragment(alarmsRvAdapter)
            }
            else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my adapter:

```
class AlarmsRvAdapter @Inject constructor(
    private val onItemSelectListener: OnItemSelectListener
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsRvAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var alarmsList: List<Alarm> = emptyList()

    class ViewHolder(view: View, onItemSelectListener: OnItemSelectListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvTime: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime)
        val tvLabel: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel)

        init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val currentPosition = bindingAdapterPosition
                if (currentPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    onItemSelectListener.onItemClick(currentPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemSelectListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_alarm, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, onItemSelectListener)
    }

    ....

}
```

What is the right approach for this?

Comment: Use @Inject lateinit var alarmsRvAdapter: AlarmsRvAdapter in AlarmsFragment. As you can't do Constructor Injection in class annotated with Android Entry Point.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal No, you are wrong. You can constructor inject inside a fragment. Please look [here](https://medium.com/supercharges-mobile-product-guide/fragmentfactory-with-dagger-and-hilt-31ee17babf73)

Comment: Did you  tried to inject it via @Provides?